# localhost MAMP - index.php cannot be found, htaccess error?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a web app and I wanted to make the URLs nice. Now this question has been asked and answered so many times. My app with it's htaccess works fine on the web. No issues. However as soon as I put it on a localhost environment, it breaks.

Here is my .htaccess rewrite rules:

```
Options -MultiViews 

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

When I go to `localhost/app/settings/`, I get the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
```

However, when I go to localhost/app/index.php/settings/, it works. What's the issue with this? I can't seem to find this issue anywhere.

I'm using MAMP on Max OSX.

Comment: What is your document root defined as on your local machine?

Comment: Um, well it works if you go to localhost/app/, the main screen appears there. localhost just has a blank index.html inside it as I want to organise things into folders for uniformity.

Comment: Ah, removing rewrite base works. I was having this issue before I added it in. Maybe it was just cached. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, that is why I was asking your what your doc root was. It would probably still work too if you used `/app` for the rewritebase since it appears your real doc root is at the localhost level.